# jQuery Button to check all checkboxes disappers on start

Tags: jquery, button, checkbox

Why is my button always disappearing on start ?
I want to check and uncheck alls checkboxes with one button.
Can't get a solution.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');          
    })
})
</script>
<div id="button">
<input type="button" class="check" value="check all" />
</div>
<div id="check">
   <input type="checkbox"  /> Checkbox  1
   <input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox  2
   <input type="checkbox"  /> Checkbox  3
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#checkAll").click(function () {
     $('#check input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);

 });
```

Comment: thX thats an easy way to do it !

Comment: Yes, I was too lazy to test out an elegant method. If you're going to accept this as the legit answer though, you should include the answer to the question, not just the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Read the definition of Toggle:  https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

*Description: Display or hide the matched elements.*

Try using click() instead.